# Why does Fiddle not register any web access when Android studio installer is downloading platform components?

Tags: android-studio, fiddler

I usually run Fiddler alongside with any application that may access internet. It catches logs of traffic from any of them. But now I am running the installer for Android studio and no requests whatsoever register in Fiddler, even though Android studio installer is clearly saying that it is downloading files, and Task Manager is showing network traffic surges.

I have no filters in Fiddler. Nothing is hidden.